# Excel question combing text with numbers

Tags: microsoft-excel

Can someone tell me how I can make the following output?

I have a cell with a number for example:

- 12345 (a1)

I have a path to a file:

- ../dir/dir2/dir3

and a file extension called .jpg

I need a output in f3 like this

../dir/dir2/dir3/12345.jpg

I tried a lot of stuff like:

../dir/dir2/dir3+A1 (I know, I can't count text and numbers)

So I tried the following

../dir/dir2/dir3&A1

But nothing seems to work

Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the CONCATENATE function:

```
=CONCATENATE("../dir/dir2/dir3/",A1,".jpg")
```

Comment: Commas between the items, not semi-colons. Nice answer, you beat me to it :)

Comment: I have to put semi-colons. Maybe because of my regional settings (French).

Comment: interesting, that may be. I tried yours and got an error telling me it had to be commas :)

Comment: My regional settings are Turkish and I have to use semi-colons like Snark does.